# Does Istio support UDP protocol?

Tags: udp, istio

Use case, need to loadbalance UDP:69 traffic between network devices and application which is running on k8s. Does Istio support UDP traffic loadbalancing?

Comment: I added updated information. Please, validate and check as valid response help others find the correct answer. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

It seems that currently UDP is not supported

See issue

https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/1430

Answer (score 3):

Istio 1.3.3+ has support for UDP.

At the time being, information is confused because in the FAQ the information is wrong.

> **WHAT PROTOCOLS DOES ISTIO SUPPORT?** 
>   Currently, Istio supports TCP based
>   protocols. In additional to this, Istio provides additional
>   functionality, such as routing and metrics, from other protocols such
>   as http and mysql. Currently, UDP traffic is not supported.

But there is a page with correct information.

> The following protocols are supported:
>
> - grpc
> - http
> - http2
> - https
> - mongo
> - mysql*
> - redis*
> - tcp
> - tls
> - udp
>
> *These protocols are disabled by default to avoid accidentally enabling
>   experimental features. To enable them, Pilot environment variables
>   must be configured

Complete list of supported protocols are in [this page](https://istio.io/docs/ops/traffic-management/protocol-selection/)

Answer (score 1):

Update info here:latest update is here:
Next the community will be focussing on the actual proxying work within the Q1 timeframe in 2019.

Seem the envoy has submit the code changing. So Istio will support UDP soon.
https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/pull/5108